# Switched to Firebase Database 9.4.0 Memory Leak

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I recently switched my code over from Firebase Client 2.5.2+ to Firebase Database 9.4.0 and I am now getting a memory leak on a consistent basis.

This is what appears in the log,

```
09-08 19:48:48.996 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
09-08 19:48:49.006 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:3 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:3
09-08 19:48:49.006 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 3
09-08 19:48:49.036 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt rsrc of package com.google.android.gms
09-08 19:48:49.056 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
09-08 19:48:49.086 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000008/n/arm64-v8a
09-08 19:48:49.096 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is arm64-v8a
09-08 19:48:49.096 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
09-08 19:48:49.136 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt rsrc of package com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt
09-08 19:48:49.286 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
09-08 19:48:49.306 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000007/n/arm64-v8a
09-08 19:48:49.316 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is arm64-v8a
09-08 19:48:49.316 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
09-08 19:48:49.386 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 9452000
09-08 19:48:49.396 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 9452440
09-08 19:48:49.676 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/c: Token loaded from file. Expires in: 347134577 ms.
09-08 19:48:49.676 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/c: Scheduling next attempt in 346834 seconds.
09-08 19:48:49.756 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-08 19:48:49.766 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@c781c09
09-08 19:48:49.766 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@fa4de0e
09-08 19:48:49.766 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@fa4de0e
09-08 19:48:49.796 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/System.err: mkdir failed: EEXIST (File exists) : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt/cache/debug
09-08 19:48:49.796 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/System.err: mkdir failed: EEXIST (File exists) : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt/cache
09-08 19:48:49.806 5535-6225/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-08 19:48:49.806 5535-6225/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-08 19:48:49.866 5535-6225/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 77 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 5535, getuid(): 10414
09-08 19:48:49.866 5535-6225/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 77
09-08 19:48:49.866 5535-6225/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-08 19:48:49.866 5535-6225/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-08 19:48:49.866 5535-6225/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 77 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 5535, getuid(): 10414
09-08 19:48:49.886 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
09-08 19:48:49.926 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt.MapsActivity isFragment :false
09-08 19:48:49.936 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
09-08 19:48:49.936 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{d79e00b I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
09-08 19:48:49.996 5535-6225/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 84 with tag 3000110100000000{805310721,0} uid -1, pid: 5535, getuid(): 10414
09-08 19:48:50.006 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/System.out: MAPSonAuthStateChanged:signed_in:r3j0QrNzWHQ0U3Cdjz5Py110X6y2
09-08 19:48:50.066 5535-5800/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
09-08 19:48:50.116 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
09-08 19:48:50.126 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f5c90dea8
09-08 19:48:50.136 5535-6225/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 77
09-08 19:48:50.146 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2040]-format:2
09-08 19:48:50.206 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt.MapsActivity
09-08 19:48:50.206 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt.MapsActivity
09-08 19:48:50.206 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
09-08 19:48:50.266 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
09-08 19:48:50.266 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
09-08 19:48:50.266 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
09-08 19:48:50.266 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
09-08 19:48:50.266 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
09-08 19:48:50.266 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
09-08 19:48:50.266 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; getDrawOrder(): no-op, return DrawOrder.HEADS_UP_DISPLAY
09-08 19:48:50.286 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.376 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.416 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.446 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.476 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.486 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.526 5535-5546/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 23351(693KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(4MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 192MB/192MB, paused 25.943ms total 104.066ms
09-08 19:48:50.526 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.536 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.566 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.586 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.606 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.686 5535-5541/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/art: Suspending all threads took: 76.794ms
09-08 19:48:50.686 5535-5546/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15513(565KB) AllocSpace objects, 24(6MB) LOS objects, 7% free, 189MB/205MB, paused 46.811ms total 161.788ms
09-08 19:48:50.716 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.736 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.746 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.756 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.776 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.786 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.806 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.826 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.836 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.856 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.876 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.886 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:50.906 5535-6275/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/Google Maps Android API: GLHudOverlay deprecated; draw(): no-op
09-08 19:48:51.106 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-08 19:48:51.146 5535-5541/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/art: Suspending all threads took: 36.104ms
09-08 19:48:51.576 5535-5546/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 278200(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 12(6MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 230MB/230MB, paused 38.106ms total 428.917ms
09-08 19:48:51.656 5535-5541/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/art: Suspending all threads took: 42.349ms
09-08 19:48:51.906 5535-6277/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
09-08 19:48:51.946 5535-6277/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt rsrc of package com.google.android.gms
09-08 19:48:51.966 5535-6277/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:1
09-08 19:48:51.966 5535-6277/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 1
09-08 19:48:51.976 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:51.996 5535-5546/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 70069(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 11(22MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 225MB/241MB, paused 14.201ms total 94.583ms
09-08 19:48:51.996 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 11.582ms for cause Alloc
09-08 19:48:51.996 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.016 5535-6277/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is arm64-v8a
09-08 19:48:52.016 5535-6277/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
09-08 19:48:52.016 5535-6277/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/GoogleCertificates: com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates module is loaded
09-08 19:48:52.076 5535-5546/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 50945(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 249MB/249MB, paused 5.239ms total 47.605ms
09-08 19:48:52.156 5535-5541/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/art: Suspending all threads took: 39.823ms
09-08 19:48:52.156 5535-5546/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.245ms
09-08 19:48:52.166 5535-5546/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 33547(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(15MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 234MB/250MB, paused 6.064ms total 73.149ms
09-08 19:48:52.196 5535-6277/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 163 Google release certificates
09-08 19:48:52.196 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.196 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.196 5535-6277/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt D/GoogleCertificatesImpl: Fetched 318 Google certificates
09-08 19:48:52.206 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 33137(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 233MB/249MB, paused 2.273ms total 15.101ms
09-08 19:48:52.246 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.256 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 13.671ms for cause Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.256 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.266 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.326 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 183(18KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(23MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 228MB/244MB, paused 622us total 63.926ms
09-08 19:48:52.366 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.366 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 9.222ms for cause Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.366 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.376 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.436 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 264MB to 256MB
09-08 19:48:52.436 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 37(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 248MB/256MB, paused 627us total 56.868ms
09-08 19:48:52.446 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.446 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 248MB/256MB, paused 507us total 5.864ms
09-08 19:48:52.456 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.526 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 264MB to 256MB
09-08 19:48:52.526 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 248MB/256MB, paused 513us total 72.830ms
09-08 19:48:52.536 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 19MB allocation
09-08 19:48:52.536 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.596 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 264MB to 256MB
09-08 19:48:52.596 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(128B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 248MB/256MB, paused 534us total 65.833ms
09-08 19:48:52.606 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 20169966 byte allocation with 8353792 free bytes and 7MB until OOM"
09-08 19:48:52.606 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.606 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.616 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(368B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 248MB/256MB, paused 557us total 5.973ms
09-08 19:48:52.616 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.686 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 264MB to 256MB
09-08 19:48:52.686 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14(512B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 248MB/256MB, paused 677us total 64.068ms
09-08 19:48:52.696 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.278ms
09-08 19:48:52.696 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.756 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 264MB to 256MB
09-08 19:48:52.756 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 248MB/256MB, paused 505us total 60.523ms
09-08 19:48:52.766 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 19MB allocation
09-08 19:48:52.766 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
09-08 19:48:52.836 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 264MB to 256MB
09-08 19:48:52.836 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1(32B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 248MB/256MB, paused 486us total 69.653ms
09-08 19:48:52.836 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Starting a blocking GC HomogeneousSpaceCompact
09-08 19:48:53.066 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 264MB to 256MB
09-08 19:48:53.066 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/art: HomogeneousSpaceCompact marksweep + semispace GC freed 2(64B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 248MB/256MB, paused 227.030ms total 227.030ms
09-08 19:48:53.066 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 20169966 byte allocation with 8349984 free bytes and 7MB until OOM"
09-08 19:48:53.086 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                                              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20169966 byte allocation with 8349984 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
                                                                                  at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:629)
                                                                                  at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:60)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:44)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:92)
                                                                                  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                                  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
09-08 19:48:53.086 5535-5535/com.leskoenterprises.buddybelt I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5535 SIG: 9
```

Also, my typical event listeners look like this,

```
   public void getEmail(String uid) {
//        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // This is static.. I thought maybe it was because I was instantiating it over and over again...
        Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("emails").equalTo(uid);
        queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                System.out.println("GETKEY: GETUIDS: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                String useremail = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Should I be removing the event listeners? If so, how should I be doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a minimal project that reproduces this memory leak? A regular Java/JVM program would be ideal, but otherwise a minimal Android app is fine too.

Comment: I am not completely sure what creates the leak, I just know that when I converted over to firebase.database 9.4.0 i started experiencing the issues. I am also not sure how to do what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

On firebase 3 the callback has changed. 
This is how you would normally do a call back.

```
queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my own issue...

was using

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

and it was pulling my entire DB multiple times...

If moving from 2.5.2 firebase use:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReferenceFromUrl("https://<your-app>.firebaseio.com/path/to/data");
```

as replacement..